# Alignment of View Elements within a LinearLayout

Tags: android

I hate to ask this question; for some reason I can't figure it out on my own.  I have a vertical LinearLayout that contains a custom View that I've defined in my app and and a TextView.  I'd like my custom View to be aligned on the top of the screen and the TextView to be aligned at the bottom of the screen.  Unfortunately, no matter what changes I make to the attributes of the XML file, my custom View always seems to be centered vertically when I run the emulator.  The xml is like the following:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="top">

    <CustomView
     android:id="@+id/customID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tileSize="24"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="@string/droidtactoe_layout_text"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="24sp" android:textColor="#00000000" android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, given your rules ("I'd like my custom View to be aligned on the top of the screen and the TextView to be aligned at the bottom of the screen"), I would recommend a `RelativeLayout`, as it will be simpler. Just use `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` on the `CustomView` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on the `TextView`, and dump all the `gravity`/`layout_gravity` stuff.

If your `CustomView` still misbehaves, temporarily replace it with a `Button` or something. If the `Button` then lays out as you expect, then there is something wrong in the implementation of your `CustomView`. If you are inheriting from a real `View` (e.g., `CustomView` is a subclass of `TextView`), you should inherit all the right functionality for laying things out. If your `CustomView` is simply a subclass of `View`, there might be some things you need to override or call that you aren't. I haven't made a custom `View` subclass, only subclasses of stuff like `LinearLayout`, so I'm not 100% certain what you would be missing.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you!  It was a problem in the CustomView.  I was using a modified version of the overridden View from the Snake demo.  That demo was using an X and Y offset that was defined in onSizeChanged based on the height and width of the View.  I was then using those offsets in the onDraw method to pad the dimensions of the object I was trying to draw.

For a reason that doesn't make sense to me now, I assumed that the width and height of the view would be limited based on the content that was being written in onDraw b/c of setting the layout Width and Height to wrapContent.  However, the width and height that was being passed in to onSizeChanged was the dimensions of the entire screen.  As a result, those offsets were forcing my Custom View to fill the whole screen.  I removed the offsets and the problem seems to be solved.

Again, thank you very much!